# Two element presentation of $\mathrm{GL}(2,3).$

Tags: finite-groups, gap

I am tying to find two element presentation of $\mathrm{GL}(2,3)$ with $48$ elements.
I am trying to prove (which may be wrong ) that presentation of $\mathrm{GL}(2,3)$ is $\{a,b\mid a^3,b^2,(ab)^8\}$ where $a=\begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 1  \\
    2       & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 0  \\
    0       & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$ I also tried with GAP as

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup("a","b");;
gap> g:=f/[f.1^2,f.2^3,(f.1*f.2)^8];
<fp group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap>Size(g);
#I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit
```

Its does not calculate the order either. I Don't know GAP properly. Please help me to find its presentation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your proposed presentation doesn't look like a presentation of a finite group. Where did you find it? Also, relatedly, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19871/presentation-of-gl2-3

Comment: i did't find its anywhere ....its just my estimate..

Comment: But given link does not gives two elements presentation of group...

Comment: Are you sure a 2 element presentation exists? One surely exists for $PSL(2,3)$, but I don't know about $GL(2,3)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current presentation is for an infinite group, which is why GAP runs out of space.

Your guess was close though. The following is a correct presentation.

$\langle a,b\mid a^2,b^3,(ab)^8,(ab)^4(ab^{-1})^4 \rangle$

You can verify this with the following GAP commands:

```
f:=FreeGroup("a","b");
a:=f.1;
b:=f.2;
g:=f/[a^2,b^3,(a*b)^8,(a*b)^4*(a*b^-1)^4];
Size(g);
StructureDescription(g);
```

Comment: are $a$ and $b$ same as mention by me??...

Comment: No, I think I switched $a$ and $b$. My $a$ has order $2$ and my $b$ has order $3$. You will need to check if your matrices obey the relations.

Comment: ok thank you very much.......

Comment: Please can you suggest me how to find all elements of this group in a and b form that is words of a and b? Is there some algorithm in GAP to find all elements of this group in a and b form ....Thanks.

Comment: @neelkanth This is a different question that should be posted separately

Comment: Ok i will post it differently..